# Initialize std::shared_ptr<T> from std::shared_ptr<void>

Tags: c++, casting, stl, initialization, shared-ptr

I run into it when trying to "copy" from `std::shared_ptr<void>` to templated `std::shared_ptr<T>`. It looks like this:

```
template < >
class TDynamic< void >
{
protected:
    std::shared_ptr< void > m_pointer;
public:
    // Here i got constructors, functions etc
    template < typename U >
    TDynamic< U > SwitchType()
    {
        TDynamic< U > returnValue;
        returnValue.m_pointer = std::shared_ptr< U >(m_pointer); // error here
    }
};
```

The error says this:

```
c:\...path_here...\tdynamic.hpp(426): error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'const std::shared_ptr< void >' to 'std::shared_ptr< T >'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=grim::Actor
1>          ]
1>  c:\...path_here...\tdynamic.hpp(426): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Compiler & IDE: Visual Studio 2015 Community

This is necessary to me for this situation. Lets say I have class "Actor" and derived class "APlayer"

```
class Actor
{
public:
};
class APlayer
    : public Actor
{
public:
};

int main()
{ // some code here
    TDynamic< APlayer > test1(new APlayer);
    TDynamic< void > test2(test1);
    TDynamic< Actor > test3(test2); // error here
}
```

I could paste the whole code here but its like 550 lines and most of it does not matter. I just need to copy that `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Check out [`static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast), but be really careful about doing this.

Comment: _"I could paste the whole code here but its like 550 lines and most of it does not matter"_ Read about how to construct a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast):

```
returnValue.m_pointer = static_pointer_cast<U>(m_pointer);
```

It's up to you to guarantee that this cast is legal (it's defined to be as legal as `static_cast<U*>(m_pointer.get())`).

Comment: Thanks dude, that was what I was looking for.
Dzięki :D